# How to get that colored bar out of InputText? - Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I'm developing an app, and I'm having a little problem. I want to make these "TextInputLayout" look like this:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

I want to take these colored lines at the bottom, I want to always make it gray and thin.

This is my code:

```
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        style="@style/EDIT_TEXT_DAY"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom style. `boxStrokeWidth` is the key value here. You can add textColor, size, etc

```
 <style name="EditTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Then set the style on the `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/EditTextInputLayoutStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```